# RESTEasy 404 not found

Tags: java, maven, jax-rs, wildfly, resteasy

i'm trying to create an API using RESTEasy, i've been looking for hours on differents topics but none could resolve my issues.

I spent one hour trying different url's, none worked, the project used to work when i was using jersey but the fact is that i'm on wildfly 10 so it's a bit complicated to deal without runtime (or maybe not but i already lost so much time configuring everything that i'm exhausted with such steps).

Here is my WEB.XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
    <display-name>api</display-name>
    <servlet>
        <description>JAX-RS Tools Generated - Do not modify</description>
        <servlet-name>RestEasy</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>api</param-name>
            <param-value>api</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>RestEasy</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Here is my Application class

```
@ApplicationPath("/api")
public class JaxRSActivator extends Application {

    public JaxRSActivator() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        System.out.println("Je passe dans le constructeur de l'application");
    }

}
```

Here is an exposed service :

```
package api;

import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

import entities.ApiUser;

@Path("ApiUser")

    public class ApiUserAPI {

        @POST
        @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        public Response createUser(ApiUser user) {
            System.out.println("JE PASSE DANS LE POST");
            if (user.getUsername() == null && user.getPwd() == null)
                return Response.status(404).build();
            return Response.status(200).build();
        }

        @GET
        @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        public Response findUser() {
            System.out.println("JE PASSE DANS LE GET");
            return Response.status(200).build();
        }

    }
```

Here is the pom

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
    <artifactId>resteasy-jaxrs</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.2.Final</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jboss.resteasy/resteasy-jackson-provider -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
    <artifactId>resteasy-jackson-provider</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.19.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

I've been working 3 hours on this and i'm not even able to catch a GET. As far as i can remember on all topics i've been through, there were almost 10 differents possibles URL to send this request. I think i tried them all.

Could someone tell me what's wrong in it and eventually the url i should use to send this damn GET request ?

ThanksFully yours,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few things you must pay attention to:

1. In a container that implements the Servelt API 3.x, such as WildFly 10, you don't need the `web.xml` deployment descriptor when deploying a simple web application. In your situation, you can safely remove it. Keep the things simple to start.
2. In your `pom.xml`, ensure you have the same version of all RESTEasy artifacts.
3. Register the `ApiUserAPI` class in your `JaxRSActivator` class by using the following lines:

```java
@Override
public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
    Set<Class<?>> classes = new HashSet<Class<?>>();
    classes.add(ApiUserAPI.class);
    return classes;
}
```

4. The URL should be `http://[host]:[port]/[context]/api/ApiUser`.

Comment: Is it possible to do the opposite? I mean to keep the web.xml file and removing the class extending Application's class